# Find index of last occurrence of a sub-string using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, search, sql-server-2000

Is there a straightforward way of finding the index of the last occurrence of a string using SQL?  I am using SQL Server 2000 right now.  I basically need the functionality that the .NET `System.String.LastIndexOf` method provides.  A little googling revealed this - [Function To Retrieve Last Index](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL+Aids/31116/) - but that does not work if you pass in a "text" column expression.  Other solutions found elsewhere work only so long as the text you are searching for is 1 character long.

I will probably have to cook a function up.  If I do so, I will post it here so you folks can look at it and maybe make use of.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are limited to [small list of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for text data type.

All I can suggest is start with `PATINDEX`, but work backwards from `DATALENGTH-1, DATALENGTH-2, DATALENGTH-3` etc until you get a result or end up at zero (DATALENGTH-DATALENGTH)

This really is something that `SQL Server 2000` simply can't handle.

**Edit for other answers** : REVERSE is not on the list of functions that can be used with text data in SQL Server 2000

Comment: Yeah, its pretty awkward.  This seems like it ought to be simple, only it isn't!

Comment: ...this is why SQL 2005 has varchar(max) to allow normal functions

Comment: Ah! so "varchar(max)" is a SQL 2005 thing, which explains why it didn't work when I tried it on SQL 2000.

Comment: DATALENGTH fails to produce the correct result for me, though LENGTH works.

Comment: @Tequila and others:  `DATALENGTH` returns the number of bytes not characters. Therefore, `DATALENGTH` returns 2 x the number of characters in a string for `NVARCHAR` strings.  `LEN`, however, returns the number of characters, _minus any trailing whitespace_.  I never use `DATALENGTH` for character length calculation unless trailing whitespace is significant and I know for sure that my datatypes are consistent, whether they be `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`

Answer (score 211):

Straightforward way? No, but I've used the reverse. Literally.

In prior routines, to find the last occurence of a given string, I used the REVERSE() function, followed CHARINDEX, followed again by REVERSE to restore the original order. For instance:

```
SELECT
   mf.name
  ,mf.physical_name
  ,reverse(left(reverse(physical_name), charindex('\', reverse(physical_name)) -1))
 from sys.master_files mf
```

shows how to extract the actual database file names from from their "physical names", no matter how deeply nested in subfolders.  This does search for only one character (the backslash), but you can build on this for longer search strings.

The only downside is, I don't know how well this will work on TEXT data types.  I've been on SQL 2005 for a few years now, and am no longer conversant with working with TEXT -- but I seem to recall you could use LEFT and RIGHT on it?

Philip

Comment: Sorry -- I'm pretty sure I never did back when I was working with 2000, and I currently do not have access to any SQL 2000 installations.

Comment: Nice one! I modified for my own needs: email.Substring(0, email.lastIndexOf('@')) == SELECT LEFT(email, LEN(email)-CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(email)))

Comment: why not just use right instead of left on the original instead of an extra reverse

Comment: Perfect solution. I performed a directory listing from a UNIX FTP into a temporary table named #CommandOutput, and there was no easy way to extract just the filenames. This does it: SELECT Readline, REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Readline), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Readline)) -1)) from #CommandOutput

Comment: I reviewed this ten-plus years after originally posting this answer. Recommend reviewing Mptje's and Binoj's replies (which I've upvoted), they both raise valid points.

Answer (score 139):

The simplest way is....

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([field]),0,CHARINDEX('[expr]',REVERSE([field]))))
```

Comment: +1 Because NOT fire error like 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function' if no match was found

Comment: If your `[expr]` is longer than 1 symbol, you need to reverse it too!

Answer (score 76):

If you are using Sqlserver 2005 or above, using `REVERSE` function many times is detrimental to performance, below code is more efficient.

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(50) = 'My\Super\Long\String\With\Long\Words'
DECLARE @FindChar VARCHAR(1) = '\'

-- text before last slash
SELECT LEFT(@FilePath, LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@FilePath))) AS Before
-- text after last slash
SELECT RIGHT(@FilePath, CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@FilePath))-1) AS After
-- the position of the last slash
SELECT LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@FilePath)) + 1 AS LastOccuredAt
```

Comment: It might seem obvious in hindsight, but if you are searching for a string instead of a single character, you have to do: LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@FindString),REVERSE(@FilePath))

Answer (score 19):

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(50) = 'My\Super\Long\String\With\Long\Words'
DECLARE @FindChar VARCHAR(1) = '\'

SELECT LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@FilePath)) AS LastOccuredAt
```

Answer (score 7):

Old but still valid question, so heres what I created based on the info provided by others here.

```
create function fnLastIndexOf(@text varChar(max),@char varchar(1))
returns int
as
begin
return len(@text) - charindex(@char, reverse(@text)) -1
end
```

Comment: Returns -1 if char is the first character of the string

Answer (score 7):

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ap_description),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ap_description)),len(ap_description)))
```

worked better for me

Answer (score 7):

This worked very well for me.

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([field]), CHARINDEX(REVERSE('[expr]'), REVERSE([field])) + DATALENGTH('[expr]'), DATALENGTH([field])))
```

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I know this is an old thread, but a tally table could do this in SQL2000 (or any other database):

```
DECLARE @str CHAR(21),
        @delim CHAR(1)
 SELECT @str = 'Your-delimited-string',
        @delim = '-'

SELECT
    MAX(n) As 'position'
FROM
    dbo._Tally
WHERE
    substring(@str, _Tally.n, 1) = @delim
```

A tally table is just a table of incrementing numbers.

The `substring(@str, _Tally.n, 1) = @delim` gets the position of each delimiter, then you just get the maximum position in that set.

Tally tables are awesome. If you haven't used them before, there is a good article on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

*EDIT: Removed `n <= LEN(TEXT_FIELD)`, as you can't use LEN() on the TEXT type. As long as the `substring(...) = @delim` remains though the result is still correct.

Comment: Nice.  I think this is effectively the same solution though as the accepted answer by gbn; you're just using a table to store the integers 1, 2, 3 etc. that are subtracted from DATALENGTH and reading from the first character forward instead of the last character back.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the index of the last space in a string of words, you can use this expression
RIGHT(name, (CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name),0)) to return the last word in the string.  This is helpful if you want to parse out the last name of a full name that includes initials for the first and /or middle name.

Answer (score 3):

This answer uses MS SQL Server 2008 (I don't have access to MS SQL Server 2000), but the way I see it according to the OP are 3 situations to take into consideration. From what I've tried no answer here covers all 3 of them:

1. Return the last index of a search character in a given string.
2. Return the last index of a search sub-string (more than just a single 
   character) in a given string.
3. If the search character or sub-string is not in the given string return `0`

The function I came up with takes 2 parameters:

`@String NVARCHAR(MAX)` : The string to be searched

`@FindString NVARCHAR(MAX)` : Either a single character or a sub-string to get the last 
                              index of in `@String`

It returns an `INT` that is either the positive index of `@FindString` in `@String` or `0` meaning that `@FindString` is not in `@String`

Here's an explanation of what the function does:

1. Initializes `@ReturnVal` to `0` indicating that `@FindString` is not in `@String`
2. Checks the index of the `@FindString` in `@String` by using `CHARINDEX()`
3. If the index of `@FindString` in `@String` is `0`, `@ReturnVal` is left as `0`
4. If the index of `@FindString` in `@String` is `> 0`, `@FindString` is in `@String` so 
   it calculates the last index of `@FindString` in `@String` by using `REVERSE()`
5. Returns `@ReturnVal` which is either a positive number that is the last index of 
   `@FindString` in `@String` or `0` indicating that `@FindString` is not in `@String`

Here's the create function script (copy and paste ready):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_LastIndexOf] 
(@String NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @FindString NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnVal INT = 0
    IF CHARINDEX(@FindString,@String) > 0
        SET @ReturnVal = (SELECT LEN(@String) - 
        (CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@FindString),REVERSE(@String)) + 
        LEN(@FindString)) + 2)  
    RETURN @ReturnVal
END
```

Here's a little bit that conveniently tests the function:

```
DECLARE @TestString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'My_sub2_Super_sub_Long_sub1_String_sub_With_sub_Long_sub_Words_sub2_'
, @TestFindString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'sub'

SELECT dbo.fn_LastIndexOf(@TestString,@TestFindString)
```

I have only run this on MS SQL Server 2008 because I don't have access to any other version but from what I've looked into this should be good for 2008+ at least.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse both your string and your substring, then search for the first occurrence.

Comment: Good point. I don't have 2000 now, and I cannot recall if I could do it when I did.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a several years old question, but...

On `Access 2010`, you can use `InStrRev()` to do this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers return an actual string whereas I had more need to know the actual index int.  And the answers that do that seem to over-complicate things.  Using some of the other answers as inspiration, I did the following...

First, I created a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LastIndexOf] (@stringToFind varchar(max), @stringToSearch varchar(max))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (LEN(@stringToSearch) - CHARINDEX(@stringToFind,REVERSE(@stringToSearch))) + 1
END
GO
```

Then, in your query you can simply do this:

```
declare @stringToSearch varchar(max) = 'SomeText: SomeMoreText: SomeLastText'

select dbo.LastIndexOf(':', @stringToSearch)
```

The above should return 23 (the last index of ':')

Hope this made it a little easier for someone!

Answer (score 1):

I know that it will be inefficient but have you considered casting the `text` field to `varchar` so that you can use the solution provided by the website you found?  I know that this solution would create issues as you could potentially truncate the record if the length in the `text` field overflowed the length of your `varchar` (not to mention it would not be very performant).

Since your data is inside a `text` field (and you are using SQL Server 2000) your options are limited.

Comment: Yes, casting to "varchar" is not an option as the data being processed frequently exceeds the maximum that can be held in a "varchar".  Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

`@indexOf = <whatever characters you are searching for in your string>`

`@LastIndexOf = LEN([MyField]) -  CHARINDEX(@indexOf, REVERSE([MyField]))`

Haven't tested, it might be off by one because of zero index, but works in `SUBSTRING` function when chopping off from `@indexOf` characters to end of your string

`SUBSTRING([MyField], 0, @LastIndexOf)`

Answer (score 1):

This code works even if the substring contains more than 1 character.

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(100) = 'My_sub_Super_sub_Long_sub_String_sub_With_sub_Long_sub_Words'
DECLARE @FindSubstring VARCHAR(5) = '_sub_'

-- Shows text before last substing
SELECT LEFT(@FilePath, LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@FindSubstring), REVERSE(@FilePath)) - LEN(@FindSubstring) + 1) AS Before
-- Shows text after last substing
SELECT RIGHT(@FilePath, CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@FindSubstring), REVERSE(@FilePath)) -1) AS After
-- Shows the position of the last substing
SELECT LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@FindSubstring), REVERSE(@FilePath)) AS LastOccuredAt
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the nth last position of a backslash in a folder path.
Here is my solution.

```
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql/30904809#30904809
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetLastIndexOf
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLastIndexOf
(
  @expressionToFind         VARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@expressionToSearch      VARCHAR(8000)
  ,@Occurrence              INT =  1        -- Find the nth last 
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  @expressionToSearch = REVERSE(@expressionToSearch)

    DECLARE @LastIndexOf        INT = 0
            ,@IndexOfPartial    INT = -1
            ,@OriginalLength    INT = LEN(@expressionToSearch)
            ,@Iteration         INT = 0

    WHILE (1 = 1)   -- Poor man's do-while
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IndexOfPartial  = CHARINDEX(@expressionToFind, @expressionToSearch)

        IF (@IndexOfPartial = 0) 
        BEGIN
            IF (@Iteration = 0) -- Need to compensate for dropping out early
            BEGIN
                SELECT @LastIndexOf = @OriginalLength  + 1
            END
            BREAK;
        END

        IF (@Occurrence > 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @expressionToSearch = SUBSTRING(@expressionToSearch, @IndexOfPartial + 1, LEN(@expressionToSearch) - @IndexOfPartial - 1)
        END

        SELECT  @LastIndexOf = @LastIndexOf + @IndexOfPartial
                ,@Occurrence = @Occurrence - 1
                ,@Iteration = @Iteration + 1

        IF (@Occurrence = 0) BREAK;
    END

    SELECT @LastIndexOf = @OriginalLength - @LastIndexOf + 1 -- Invert due to reverse
    RETURN @LastIndexOf 
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON GetLastIndexOf TO public
GO
```

Here are my test cases which pass

```
SELECT dbo.GetLastIndexOf('f','123456789\123456789\', 1) as indexOf -- expect 0 (no instances)
SELECT dbo.GetLastIndexOf('\','123456789\123456789\', 1) as indexOf -- expect 20
SELECT dbo.GetLastIndexOf('\','123456789\123456789\', 2) as indexOf -- expect 10
SELECT dbo.GetLastIndexOf('\','1234\6789\123456789\', 3) as indexOf -- expect 5
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the part before the last occurence of the delimiter (works only for `NVARCHAR` due to `DATALENGTH` usage):

```
DECLARE @Fullstring NVARCHAR(30) = '12.345.67890.ABC';

DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(1) = '.';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Fullstring, 1, DATALENGTH(@Fullstring)/2 - CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, REVERSE(@Fullstring)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer meets the requirements of the OP. specifically it allows the needle to be more than a single character and it does not generate an error when needle is not found in haystack. It seemed to me that most (all?) of the other answers did not handle those edge cases. Beyond that I added the "Starting Position" argument provided by the native MS SQL server CharIndex function. I tried to exactly mirror the specification for CharIndex except to process right to left instead of left to right. eg I return null if either needle or haystack is null and I return zero if needle is not found in haystack. One thing that I could not get around is that with the built in function the third parameter is optional. With SQL Server user defined functions, all parameters must be provided in the call unless the function is called using "EXEC" . While the third parameter must be included in the parameter list, you can provide the keyword "default" as a placeholder for it without having to give it a value (see examples below). Since it is easier to remove the third parameter from this function if not desired than it would be to add it if needed I have included it here as a starting point.

```
create function dbo.lastCharIndex(
 @needle as varchar(max),
 @haystack as varchar(max),
 @offset as bigint=1
) returns bigint as begin
 declare @position as bigint
 if @needle is null or @haystack is null return null
 set @position=charindex(reverse(@needle),reverse(@haystack),@offset)
 if @position=0 return 0
 return (len(@haystack)-(@position+len(@needle)-1))+1
end
go

select dbo.lastCharIndex('xyz','SQL SERVER 2000 USES ANSI SQL',default) -- returns 0
select dbo.lastCharIndex('SQL','SQL SERVER 2000 USES ANSI SQL',default) -- returns 27
select dbo.lastCharIndex('SQL','SQL SERVER 2000 USES ANSI SQL',1) -- returns 27
select dbo.lastCharIndex('SQL','SQL SERVER 2000 USES ANSI SQL',11) -- returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread while searching for a solution to my similar problem which had the exact same requirement but was for a different kind of database that was also lacking the `REVERSE` function.

In my case this was for a *OpenEdge (Progress)* database, which has a slightly different syntax.  This made the `INSTR` function available to me that [most Oracle typed databases offer](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr).

So I came up with the following code:

```
SELECT 
  INSTR(foo.filepath, '/',1, LENGTH(foo.filepath) - LENGTH( REPLACE( foo.filepath, '/',  ''))) AS IndexOfLastSlash 
FROM foo
```

However, for my specific situation (being the *OpenEdge (Progress)* database) this did not result into the desired behaviour because replacing the character with an empty char gave the same length as the original string. This doesn't make much sense to me but I was able to bypass the problem with the code below:

```
SELECT 
  INSTR(foo.filepath, '/',1, LENGTH( REPLACE( foo.filepath, '/',  'XX')) - LENGTH(foo.filepath))  AS IndexOfLastSlash 
FROM foo
```

---

Now I understand that this code won't solve the problem for **T-SQL** because there is no alternative to the `INSTR` function that offers the `Occurence` property.

Just to be thorough I'll add the code needed to create this scalar function so it can be used the same way like I did in the above examples.

```
  -- Drop the function if it already exists
  IF OBJECT_ID('INSTR', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION INSTR
  GO

  -- User-defined function to implement Oracle INSTR in SQL Server
  CREATE FUNCTION INSTR (@str VARCHAR(8000), @substr VARCHAR(255), @start INT, @occurrence INT)
  RETURNS INT
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @found INT = @occurrence,
            @pos INT = @start;

    WHILE 1=1 
    BEGIN
        -- Find the next occurrence
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, @pos);

        -- Nothing found
        IF @pos IS NULL OR @pos = 0
            RETURN @pos;

        -- The required occurrence found
        IF @found = 1
            BREAK;

        -- Prepare to find another one occurrence
        SET @found = @found - 1;
        SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    END

    RETURN @pos;
  END
  GO
```

To avoid the obvious, when the `REVERSE` function is available you do not need to create this scalar function and you can just get the required result like this:

```
SELECT
  LEN(foo.filepath) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(foo.filepath))+1 AS LastIndexOfSlash 
FROM foo
```

Answer (score 0):

handles lookinng for something > 1 char long.
feel free to increase the parm sizes if you like.

couldnt resist posting

```
drop function if exists lastIndexOf
go 
create function lastIndexOf(@searchFor varchar(100),@searchIn varchar(500))
returns int
as
begin 

if LEN(@searchfor) > LEN(@searchin) return 0 
declare @r varchar(500), @rsp varchar(100)
select @r = REVERSE(@searchin)
select @rsp = REVERSE(@searchfor)
return len(@searchin) - charindex(@rsp, @r) - len(@searchfor)+1
end
```

and tests

```
select dbo.lastIndexof('greg','greg greg asdflk; greg sadf' )  -- 18
select dbo.lastIndexof('greg','greg greg asdflk; grewg sadf' )  --5
select dbo.lastIndexof(' ','greg greg asdflk; grewg sadf' ) --24
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread has been going for a while. I'll offer a solution covering different basis with example:

```
declare @aStringData varchar(100) = 'The quick brown/fox jumps/over the/lazy dog.pdf'
/*
The quick brown/fox jumps/over the/lazy dog.pdf
fdp.god yzal/eht revo/spmuj xof/nworb kciuq ehT
*/

select
    Len(@aStringData) - CharIndex('/', Reverse(@aStringData)) + 1 [Char Index],
    -- Get left side of character, without the character '/'
    Left(@aStringData, Len(@aStringData) - CharIndex('/', Reverse(@aStringData))) [Left excluding char],
    -- Get left side of character, including the character '/'
    Left(@aStringData, Len(@aStringData) - CharIndex('/', Reverse(@aStringData)) + 1) [Left including char],
    -- Get right side of character, without the character '/'
    Right(@aStringData, CharIndex('/', Reverse(@aStringData)) - 1) [Right including char]
```

To get char position, need to reverse the string as CharIndex gets the first occurrence. Remembering as we're reversing, the CharIndex cursor will land on the other side of the character we're finding. So expect to compensate by -1 or +1, depending if wanting to get left or right side portion of string.