# T-SQL Get File Extension Name from a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column that contains the entire file name, the data looks like:

```
FilePath                       FileSize
------------------------------ --------
dsch2_chs_wyj.rar              694KB
AllInOneHash.rar               19KB
FilePropertyModifier.rar       12KB
jquery_1_7_api_chm_chs.rar     285KB
startupmgr.rar                 38KB
JQueryTableExample_Edi.rar     33KB
hdpartioncalc_csharp.rar       49KB
XMLMenuTest.zip                3KB
```

Now I want to extract the file extension name, like `.rar` and insert into a new table.

```
INSERT INTO Attachment
  (
    Id,
    [FileName],
    ExtensionName,
    StoredPath,
    CreateOn,
    UploaderIP,
    DataBinary
  )
SELECT ba.Id,
       ba.Title,
       '{Extension Name}',
       ba.FilePath,
       GETDATE(),
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   BlogAttachment ba
```

But T-SQL doesn't have a `LastIndexOf()` function. How can I cut the substring in an easy way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find index of last occurrence of a sub-string using T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql)

Comment: new table... or new column?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn sorry, i mean new colum in a new table, just as the code pasted above. The problem is solved. thanks anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove extensions from filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241635/remove-extensions-from-filename)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN filepath LIKE '%.%' THEN RIGHT(filepath, Len(filepath) - 
                                                       Charindex('.', filepath)) 
         ELSE filepath 
       END FilePath 
FROM   tbl1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/483b3/1)

Comment: Doesn't handle files with multiple "." in name.

Comment: Wasn't part of the requirement.

Comment: this one doesn't handle all cases. Gordon Linoff answer works better for me

Comment: It's a tacit requirement.

Comment: File extension is the part of the string after the **last** period. The question was how to get the file extension so it was part of the requirement...

Answer (score 84):

You can get the extension by doing:

```
 select reverse(left(reverse(FilePath), charindex('.', reverse(FilePath)) - 1))
```

However, I would recommend that you check that there is a `'.'` in the name first:

```
 select (case when FilePath like '%.%'
              then reverse(left(reverse(FilePath), charindex('.', reverse(FilePath)) - 1))
              else ''
         end) as Extension
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO . . . The original *did* work on my test example, but I fixed it.

Comment: @Abhishek . . . The second query works in that case, as explicitly stated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When looking for specific extensions, and dealing with texts that do have many dots, the following provides a more specific approach.

```
with extensionTable ([extension]) AS
(
    SELECT '.pdf'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.txt'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.doc'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.docx'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.xls'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.xlsx'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.ppt'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.pptx'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.zip'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.tar.gz'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.htm'
    UNION ALL SELECT '.html'
)

SELECT T2.[extension]
        , T1.[document_file_name]
FROM tbl T1
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 [extension] 
                FROM extensionTable
                WHERE CHARINDEX([extension], T1.[document_file_name]) > 0
                ORDER BY CHARINDEX([extension], T1.[document_file_name]) DESC, LEN([extension]) DESC
            ) T2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get file extension in this way:

```
select right('https://google.com/1.png', charindex('.', reverse('https://google.com/1.png') + '.') - 1)
```

And You can get file name in this way:

```
select right('https://google.com/1.png', charindex('/', reverse('https://google.com/1.png') + '/') - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its too late to answer but i found the solution how can get extension of an image or file from sql column and also get any string after any keyword or "/"or ".".... just replace the "." with your keyword.

```
    SELECT SUBSTR("string_or_colname",(SELECT POSITION("." IN"string_or_colname")));

    # and if you wanted to get from starting then add 0 after 
    string_or_colname,then postion
    eg :
    SELECT SUBSTR("string_or_colname",1,(SELECT POSITION("." IN"string_or_colname")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with file names and urls (without querystrings).

If you want to do it quick and dirty inline:

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([<ColumnName,,>]),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE([<ColumnName,,>])))) AS Extension 
  FROM [<TableName,,>]
```

I recommend creating a scalar function.  That way you can add more business logic to handle query strings or what have you.

To create a scalar function:

```
-- ========================================================================
-- Description: Gets extension from filename or url without a querystring
-- ========================================================================
CREATE FUNCTION get_extension 
(
    @column varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(MAX)
    SELECT @Result = REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@column),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@column))))
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

and then your query would simply look like this

```
SELECT dbo.get_extension([<ColumnName,,>]) AS Extension FROM [<TableName,,>]
```

As a side note, if you are using SSMS, you can press CNTL-M to populate the <Something,,>  variables

Answer (score -2):

```
  declare @filepath char(250) = 'c:\powersql\database\teste.txtdat'
  Declare @NewExtesion Char(15) = 'Old' 



--  @filepath char(250)                           = 'c:\powersql\database\teste.txtdat'
--  select len(@FilePath)                         = 33
--  Select Charindex('.', @filepath)              = Len of Filepath before Extension  
--  select RIGHT(rtrim(@filepath) ,len(@FilePath) - Charindex('.', @filepath) )   = txtdat (extension i would like to change)  
--  select REPLACE(@filepath, RIGHT(rtrim(@filepath) ,len(@FilePath) - Charindex('.', @filepath)), 'xxx')
       -- here i changed .txdat to xxx

-- below the full query 

SELECT 
      CASE 
         WHEN @filepath LIKE '%.%' 
               THEN  REPLACE(@filepath, RIGHT(rtrim(@filepath) ,len(@FilePath) - Charindex('.', @filepath)), @NewExtesion)
         ELSE @filepath 
       END
```

Comment: This is not what was asked for. You should just extract extension. Even taking just the ```RIGHT(...)``` will not work always (because you cannot say for sure, that there is always one ```.``` in the path). This is why the question said "But T-SQL doesn't have a ```LastIndexOf()``` function." But you might have a try to correct your answer making use of the ```REVERSE()``` function.