# Want specific part of a sku from a SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the first letters of sku from left up to the second `-`. But in output I don't want that second `-` to show up.

My input table is

[image: Input table]

Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SKU, charindex('-',SKU),  len(SKU) - charindex('-',SKU)) 
FROM tblname
```

My excepted output is

[image: desired o/p]

Comment: What "dialect" of SQL is this for? MS SqlServer? Oracle? Postgres? .... string manipulation could require some product specific function or trick...

Comment: I have no access to a SQL Server instance so I cannot propose a complete solution - only advice.
You can either write a _function_ to do this for you (possibly more efficient than trying to do all as part of a select) or - as someone else suggested, use _reverse_ to transform the problem in "I need to find the last instance of '-' in my string to isolate the SKU" to the far more tractable "I need to find the first instance of '-'" see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(SKU,0, CHARINDEX('-',SKU,(charindex('-',SKU)+1))+1) from tablename
```

Hopes this helps...

Comment: you should post the result so that we can better understand what the problem is.

Comment: @sachit Updated... is that you want?

Comment: @sachit - I saw that you posted your _expected_ output, and this is good and important to better define your problem. But I was referring to the output produced by Sankar Raj's answer. Saying only "it is not working" will not help him refining his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE('Hello-World-1'), 
                      LEN('Hello-World-1') - CHARINDEX('-',
                                                       REVERSE('Hello-World-1'))))
```

If you want to include the dash...

```
SELECT  REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE('Hello-World-1'), 1 + 
                      LEN('Hello-World-1') - CHARINDEX('-',
                                                       REVERSE('Hello-World-1'))))
```