# Display substring seperated by / in Hive

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have a column in my table with entries like:

```
this/is/my/dir/file
this/is/my/another/dir/file
```

I want to display the string without the filename:

```
this/is/my/dir/
```

This is the query which I am using:

```
select regexp_replace('this/is/my/another/dir/file','[^/]+','');
```

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve that objectives in Hive, but in SQL-server, you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600077/7882621), in which your expression should be '/'.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can use `regexp_replace` to remove the `file` and only reserve the dir path, as we know the file name does not contain the character '/' and is always located at the end of the dir path, so the regexp can be written as `'[^/]+$'`, the examples as below, it means that replace the substring with regexp `'[^/]+$'` to an empty `''`.

```
select regexp_replace('/this/is/my/dir/file','[^/]+$','') as dir;
+-------------------+
|        dir        |
+-------------------+
| /this/is/my/dir/  |
+-------------------+

select regexp_replace('this/is/my/another/dir/file','[^/]+$','') as dir;
+--------------------------+
|           dir            |
+--------------------------+
| this/is/my/another/dir/  |
+--------------------------+
```