# Getting everything after last '/'

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a path like this in my `TBL_Documents` table:

```
Uploads/Documents/6093/12/695-Graco-SW_5-15-19.pdf
```

I need to compare it to a file being uploaded now that will look like this:

```
695-Graco-SW_5-15-19.pdf
```

I want to compare the path in my table with the uploaded file name. I tried using `substring()` on the first right `/` but I don't really get how substring is really working. For example, I tried to do this:

```
select substring(right(path,1),1,1) as path from TBL_DOCUMENT
```

but it is only giving me the very first character from the right. I expected to see everything after the last `/` character.

How can I do this?

Comment: substring(@filename, [index of last '/'] + 1, len(@filename))  To get the [index of the last '/'] -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a LastIndexOf in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use an approach of finding how many characters you need to use from the right. I would do this by first reversing the string and then searching for the '/'. This will tell you how many characters from the right this '/' is. I would then use this in the `RIGHT` function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/58652)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @documentName varchar(100) = 'Uploads/Documents/6093/12/695-Graco-SW_5-15-19.pdf'

SELECT RIGHT(@documentName, CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@documentName))-1)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/58652/0)**:

```
|                          |
|--------------------------|
| 695-Graco-SW_5-15-19.pdf |
```

Answer (score 2):

`RIGHT(path,1)` means you want [1] character from the right of the path string, or 'f'.
You then wrap 'f' in a substring, asking for [1] character starting at the [1]st position of the string.  Since the expression passed to substring returns 'f', your substring also returns 'f'.

You want to use a combination of charindex and reverse to handle this appropriately.
`SUBSTRING(path,len(path) - charindex('/',reverse(path)))`.  That will not parse but it should get you on the right track.

In normal speak, this returns the string, starting with the right most '/' of the path, to the end of string.