How to decrement a number in a character-separated string
I have strings in a SQL Server table column:



SequenceId




2-10-14


2-8-15


2-8-16


2-8-16


2-17-21


2-0-5



I have to reduce the last digits after hyphen by one (as shown here):








2-10-13


2-8-14


2-8-15


2-8-15


2-17-20


2-0-4



Any help?

What if it's 0 already

I would suggest you fix your design; you are storing delimited data in your table which breaks fundamental design rules. Then the problem is as simple as UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET YourThirdColumn = YourThirdColumn - 1;

the value will be always be greater than zero.

changing database design is not an option.

you need to use STRING_SPLIT method with dash "-" as the separator, to capture the numbers. Then you can manipulate them individually... you may also need to CONVERT to integer.

Unfortunately, for you, you can't even use STRING_SPLIT as you're on 2019 and don't have access to the ordinal parameter. As for not changing the design, I really suggest you push upstream to fix it; it is fundamentally the reason why you are having a problem here.

Something like this should get you started: SELECT *, CONCAT(LEFT(sequenceid, len(sequenceid) - position + 1), cast(RIGHT(sequenceid, position - 1) AS int) - 1) FROM #data d CROSS APPLY ( SELECT charindex('-', reverse(sequenceid)) AS position) p

@Yoav24 they can't use STRING_SPLIT for the reason I state.

@ThomA per the documentation, they can use STRING_SPLIT in 2019 since the compatibility level, 150, is greater than 130. I am using 2017 and it works fine

@Yoav24 2019 version of STRING_SPLIT doesn't support ordinal (the third parameter) which is needed to do something useful with it

In 2019, I get the error "Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.", as expected, @Yoav24 . db<>fiddle You need compatibility level 160 for the ordinal parameter.

concat(left(SequenceId,len(SequenceId) -charindex('-',reverse(SequenceId))+1),right(SequenceId,charindex('-',reverse(SequenceId))-1)-1), see: DBFIDDLE

Thing thing to understand here: the reason so many have voted for the suggestion to fix the schema design is because this existing design really is broken. It's not just a preference or incremental improvement, but rather correcting something that was fundamentally unsound to begin with.

and your string is not even a comma-separated string .....

I really hope you at least have a CONSTRAINT with a definition like CHECK (DenormalisedColumn LIKE '%[0-9]-%[0-9]-%[0-9]' AND DenormalisedColumn NOT LIKE '%[^\-0-9]%' ESCAPE '\'). If not, what is 'cherries'-1 when your column has the value 'apples-pears-cherries'?

@Luuk sorry, that was my bad, edited the header a bit

These look like dates. If so, change the column type to date, then everything becomes simpler.

So apparently it will never go negative?

What month is the "0th" month, @Bohemian ? I agree, most look like dates, until you get to '2-0-5'.

@ThomA if they are dates, it's American format, so the zero would be a day. Maybe OP is using zero-based days?

If it is, they can't use a date without changing the value of the 0 @Bohemian ; SQL Server does not support 0th days/months. As such, they need to use date ranges, and then have things like 2005-02-00 be represent by the dates 2005-02-01 and 2005-03-01 (inclusive/exclusive logic).

I think  for date reprsentation 2024-01-01->2023-12-31 not 2024-01-00

Try this fugliness.  While not recommended, it seems to work.  A proper database design is what is needed, for obvious performance and coding issues.  The Common Table Expression just sets up test data and is a great way to provide example data. You really only need to select the last "joined_back" but I included the separate parts for completeness.  Adapted from this post and he should get any credit:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369450/2543416
with tbl(SequenceId) as (
  select '2-10-14' union all
  select '2-8-15' union all
  select '2-8-16' union all
  select '2-8-16' union all
  select '2-17-21' union all
  select '2-0-5'
)
select 
 LEFT(SequenceId, LEN(SequenceId) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))+1) AS first_part,
 RIGHT(SequenceId, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))-1) AS second_part,
 RIGHT(SequenceId, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))-1) - 1 as decrement,
 LEFT(SequenceId, LEN(SequenceId) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))+1) + cast(RIGHT(SequenceId, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))-1) - 1 as char(2)) as joined_back 
from tbl;


first_part  second_part decrement   joined_back
2-10-       14          13          2-10-13
2-8-        15          14          2-8-14
2-8-        16          15          2-8-15
2-8-        16          15          2-8-15
2-17-       21          20          2-17-20
2-0-        5           4           2-0-4 

It could also be written like this which aids in troubleshooting:
with tbl(SequenceId) as (
  select '2-10-14' union all
  select '2-8-15' union all
  select '2-8-16' union all
  select '2-8-16' union all
  select '2-17-21' union all
  select '2-0-5'  union all
  select null
),
tbl_splitup(first_part, second_part, decrement) as (
  select LEFT(SequenceId, LEN(SequenceId) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))+1),
    RIGHT(SequenceId, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))-1),
    RIGHT(SequenceId, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(SequenceId))-1) - 1 as decrement
  from tbl
)
-- select * from tbl_splitup
select first_part + cast(decrement as char(2)) as joined_back 
from tbl_splitup;


Adding a cross apply (select ... as Pos) P might further simplify the code by eliminating the sub-expression duplication. Fiddle.

Please try the following solution based on tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
It is a preferable way comparing with the string parsing approach that is calling a long list of functions: LEFT(), RIGHT(), LEN(), CHARINDEX(), REVERSE(), CAST(), etc. multiple times endlessly.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is tokenizing column data as XML.
XQuery FLWOR expression is traversing sequence of tokens, and when it is a last
token based on the XPath expression r[last()], subtracting its
value.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SequenceId VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (SequenceId) VALUES
('2-10-14'),
('2-8-15'),
('2-8-16'),
('2-8-16'),
('2-17-21'),
('2-0-5');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

SELECT *
    , REPLACE(x.query('
        let $last_token := (/root/r[last()])[1]
        for $token in /root/r
        return if ($token is $last_token) then data($token - 1)
            else data($token)
    ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)')
    , SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(SequenceId, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(x);

Output



id
SequenceId
result




1
2-10-14
2-10-13


2
2-8-15
2-8-14


3
2-8-16
2-8-15


4
2-8-16
2-8-15


5
2-17-21
2-17-20


6
2-0-5
2-0-4




The string processing functions are sufficient to make the change in your simple case. A simple case is replacing the first or last part of a string.
If you need to change the inner part, manipulating the charindex and substring functions is certainly sufficient to solve the problem. However, the solution will no longer be clear.
In this case, I suggest looking at an option using operations on JSON. They are also available on earlier versions of SQL Server.
See example
update test
set SequenceId= 
 concat(left(SequenceId,len(SequenceId)-charindex('-',reverse(SequenceId))+1)
  ,cast(cast(right(SequenceId,charindex('-',reverse(SequenceId))-1) as int)-1 as varchar)
 )




SequenceId
NewSequenceId - After update




2-10-13
2-10-12


2-8-14
2-8-13


2-8-15
2-8-14


2-8-15
2-8-14


2-17-20
2-17-19


2-0-4
2-0-3


4-1-9
4-1-8


4-1-99
4-1-98



fiddle
Several other examples.
Your input string (SequenceId) can be easily converted to JSON format and back to string (varchar).
There index of part begin with 0. So third part json_path is $[2].
-- for SQL Server 2017
SELECT * 
  ,trim(translate(JSON_modify('[' + replace(SequenceId,'-',',') + ']','$[2]'
        ,JSON_value('[' + replace(SequenceId,'-',',') + ']','$[2]')-1)
      ,',[]','-  ')) NewSequenceId
FROM  test

-- for SQL Server 2016
SELECT * 
  ,replace(
    replace(
     replace(JSON_modify('[' + replace(SequenceId,'-',',') + ']','$[2]'
        ,JSON_value('[' + replace(SequenceId,'-',',') + ']','$[2]')-1)
      ,',','-') 
     ,'[','')
    ,']','')NewSequenceId
FROM  test


fiddle

This is a bit long winded but works on the supplied sample data.
NOTE: It does not handle scenarios where the number to be decremented is 0 . Also, if these are some form of date, it would not work if the number is 1, as it would update it to 0 which is obviously not valid in a date.
DECLARE @t TABLE(s varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('2-10-14'), ('2-8-15'), ('2-8-16'), ('2-8-16'), ('2-17-21'), ('2-0-5');

SELECT * FROM @t;

UPDATE @t SET s = LEFT(s, CHARINDEX('-', (s), CHARINDEX('-', s)+1))
                    + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX('-', (s), CHARINDEX('-', s)+1) +1, LEN(s) - CHARINDEX('-', (s), CHARINDEX('-', s)-1)) as INT) -1 as varchar(10))
    FROM @t;

SELECT * FROM @t;

This gives the following before and after results.


I was trying to think of a clever way to do this inline:
declare @v varchar(32) = '2-3-4';
select concat(replace(left(replace(@v, '-', '    -'), 10), ' ', ''), '-', cast(parsename(replace(@v, '-', '.'), 1) as int) - 1)


Use STRING_SPLIT method
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('2-10-14', '-',1) gives 3 rows with 2,10,14 and the argument "1" gives ordinals:



Value
Ordinal




2
1


10
2


14
3



Now you want to grab the third one minus one:
SELECT value-1 FROM STRING_SPLIT('2-10-14', '-',1)
WHERE ordinal = 3

13

Rebuilding the string is the second step, I'll leave that to you. I would advise creating a function with some variables to do this easier.

This will yield the error "Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.": db<>fiddle. SQL Server 2019 does not support the ordinal parameter, which is crucial the OP's problem.

This solution, also, does not demonstrate how to get the values back into a denormalised value.

@ThomA you're the reason why no one tries to help on Stack anymore. not everything runs on db fiddle. no need to downvote everything. OP can comment on what works or doesn't work for them.

That it's a fiddle has nothing to do with it; 2019 does not support the ordinal parameter. A db<>fiddle for 2022 works fine. The OP, however, isn't using 2022. As for the downvotes, I can't vote on your question twice, and I didn't say I did downvote. The fact you've responded above is why many that do downvote don't comment; because reasons for why a answer may not work in the comments are often met with scorn.
